# Exchange Powershell Restrict OrganizationalUnit to Top Level OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-2013

I'm using the following code to check an attribute on mailboxes that reside in an specific OU:

```
Get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "MY-OU" | Select DisplayName, CustomAttribute5 |Export-csv c:\filename.csv -nti
```

I can't find a way to restrict the query to only objects that live in the top level of that OU, which is where the accounts I'm interest in are located.  If I run it as it is now, it starts pulling in mailboxes from all of the sub-containers and the job ends after 1,000 results are pulled in.  I COULD just remote the default limit, but that would mean I'm pulling down ~10,000 mailboxes vs. the couple of hundred from the top level OU that I actually need to review.

Any ideas on how limit the scope of that request?  Other AD limiting parameters don't appear to be valid for Get-mailbox (such as searchbase/searchscope/etc.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with Get-ADuser using a search scope and pipe that to Get-Mailbox

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com' -SearchScope OneLevel | ForEach {
    Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.SamAccountName
}
```

Or...

You can exclude the ones you don't want using something like this example...
(tweak as needed)

```
# Get all mailboxes from a main OU but exclude a few sub OUs
# https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1955950-get-all-mailboxes-from-a-main-ou-but-exclude-a-few-sub-ous

$TargetOU = 'OU=USA,OU=NNA,DC=NMCorp,DC=Nissan,DC=Biz'

$OUExclude = @(
    'NMCorp.Nissan.Biz/NNA/USA/US-Terminated Users'
    'NMCorp.Nissan.Biz/NNA/USA/US-Users/Shared Mailboxes'
    'NMCorp.Nissan.Biz/NNA/USA/US-Conference Rooms'
    )

$CharExclude = @(
    '!'
    '@'
    ','
    )

$Output = "$Path\NNA_Shared_Mailboxes_All_OUs_$( Get-Date -Format MMM.dd.yyyy ).csv"

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $TargetOU -ResultSize Unlimited |
    Where-Object {
            $OUExclude -notcontains $_.OrganizationalUnit -and
            $_.DisplayName -notmatch ( $CharExclude -join '|' )
        } |
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName, SamAccountName, RecipientType, RecipientTypeDetails, DistinguishedName, 
        @{ Name = "Enabled"; Expression = { ( Get-ADUser -Identity $PSItem.SamAccountName ).Enabled } } |
    Export-Csv -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation -Append
```